# How to calculate fields with dynamic ng-model names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my angular application that generates tables through directives. The fields in the tables need to have unique ng-model names so i can calculate each table seperatly.
I have solved the unique ng-model name with a counter that goes up for each table that is added and it adds the current count to the end of each ng-model name for each field.
(See my plunkr link for futher explanation).

I have a function in my app.js that will sum the fields. The function works very well when i have static ng-model names but i cant figure out how to concat the ng-model names with the current count so that the function can calculate each table seperatly when adding a number after each ng-model.
How do i fix my $scope.total function so that it works with the dynamic ng-model names?

[My plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KL32KDC75CA9ecuhNony?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.count = 0;

$scope.total = function(count){
var total = 
// I want to parseFloat the $scope.td1 + the current count.
// How does the syntax look when you concat ng-model.
parseFloat($scope.td1 + count || 0) + 
parseFloat($scope.td2 + count || 0) + 
parseFloat($scope.td3 + count || 0) +  
parseFloat($scope.td4 + count || 0) +  
parseFloat($scope.td5 + count || 0);
return total || 0;
}
});
```

**Edit:**
As a follow up question, i have added a new input to my plunkr that should display the sum of the "total" in the first two tables that are generated. This does not work as it is now and i cant figure out why.
I added a new function that should summerize the first two "total".

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but check out my answer to help you improve your AngularJS skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :
    $scope['td1'+count]

In javascript you can access an object property either with pointed notation : object.property, or with named array notation : object['property'].

In your case, $scope.td1 + count will return the value of $scope.td1 + count.

```
$scope.td12 = 10;
$scope.td1 = 3;
count = 2;

$scope.td1 + count; // 5
$scope['td1'+count]; // $scope['td12'] == $scope.td12 == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

update your total function to below code. It should work. Here is the updated plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/vRSQOvRVkUKLZ1ihvBp4?p=preview

```
$scope.total = function(count){
    // I want to parseFloat the $scope.td1 + the current count.
    // How does the syntax look when you concat ng-model.
    var total = 
    parseFloat($scope["td1" + count] || 0) + 
    parseFloat($scope["td2" + count] || 0) + 
    parseFloat($scope["td3" + count] || 0) +  
    parseFloat($scope["td4" + count] || 0) +  
    parseFloat($scope["td5" + count] || 0);
    return total || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create a self-contained table directive that keeps track of its own total and tells the parent scope whenever that changes.

This avoids having weird counters and cluttering up one scope with properties for every single input.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // the totals for each of the tables
  $scope.totals = [];
  $scope.grandTotal = 0;
  // whenever one of the table's total changes, it calls this function
  // with its new total, so we can update our grand total
  $scope.changeTotal = function(index, total) {
    $scope.totals[index] = total;
    $scope.grandTotal = sum($scope.totals);
  }
});

app.directive('myTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onTotalChange: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'table.html',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.values = [];
      // whenever one of the values the inputs are bound to changes,
      // recalculate the total for this table and tell the parent scope
      $scope.$watchCollection('values', function(values) {
        $scope.onTotalChange({
          total: sum(values)
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

// easy way to sum an array of values in modern browsers
function sum(values) {
  return values.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Grand total: {{grandTotal}}</p>
  <!-- Whenever we click the button, add a new entry to our totals array
       so a new table appears -->
  <button ng-click="totals.push(0)">New table</button>
  <!-- Render a new table for every entry in our totals array.
       Whenever that table's total changes, update its total in the array. -->
  <my-table ng-repeat="i in totals track by $index" on-total-change="changeTotal($index, total)">
  </my-table>

  <!-- This allows the directive to specify a templateUrl of 'table.html' but not
     have to actually fetch it from the server. -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="table.html">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>head 1</th>
          <th>head 2</th>
          <th>head 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[0]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[1]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[2]">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[3]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[4]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="values[5]">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you GregL, i will try it out.

Comment: Hi GregL, thank you so much for this. It works perfectly, i just have one question because i am learning angular directives.
I want to display the $scope.totals[ ] for each table that is generated into one of the cells in every table. So the sum of each table is shown in a cell in every generated table. 
Basicly, i want to pass down the totals[ ] variable to the directive template, how do i do that?